# What determines the MoveNext order in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

Scenario: I have a DAC called Table1.  That DAC has a key field, and that key field has a selector with a condition.  Let's say,

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<Table.keyField, Where<Table.fieldCheck, IsNull>>))]
```

So, on the page, the Selector works just fine; I get all keyFields from Table where fieldCheck is null.  But, when I click the navigation buttons, they completely ignore the "fieldCheck is null" condition and loads those records anyways.  How can I bind my navigation buttons to the conditions laid out in the selector?

Comment: Can you post the code of your graph (BLC) which shows how the primary view (PXSelect...) is declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing some other condition of your page, you should be able to use a filter object on your primaryview, or just limit your primary view by the same condition that you have in your Selector, you would then only retrieve the records desired.